# Как проверить значение и вывести таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как проверить значение и вывести таблицу.
Я прикрепил скриншот, который просто выводит таблицу на страницу.
Но мне нужно, чтобы проверялось 1 значение на скриншоте и выдавало 2 и 3, а сейчас просто таблица.
То есть если "статус" первого месяца "+", то таблица заполняет 2 и 3 и выводит ниже второй месяц,
а если "-", то только первый месяц.

Сейчас таблица выводит все месяцы сразу, хотелось бы, чтобы она выводила первый месяц и проверяла, а потом второй.

Еще я не совсем понимаю, как будет заполняться поле статус.

Скриншот:

[image]

Comment: @Михаил Волков, а данные выводятся из базы данных?

Comment: @Михаил Волков Без кода вывода данных и структуры таблицы в базе едва ли вам кто-то поможет. И тем более, разберётся за вас, как заполнять поле со статусом. Вы даже не написали, что это за статус.

Comment: @Михаил Волков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Код в студию!!!

Answer (score 2):

Слегка не понял, но примерно так:

```
// ...your code here...
while($row = $sth->fetch()){ // Получаем значения одного месяца
 if($row->status > 0){ // Проверяем по полю (не знаю названия и типа хранения, просто для примера)
   // Если статус в плюсе, то делай своё чёрное или не очень дело вывода
 }else{
   // Статус меньше или равен нулю, можно что-то делать, если нужно
   break; // Выходим из цикла чтобы дальше месяцы не выводились
 }
}
// ...your code here...
```